# Unable to Save to my Data to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ado.net

```vb
Try
    If MsgBox("Add this Student?", vbNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        cn.Open()
        cm = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO stud (@studID, @LN, @FN, @MI, @Course, @Year, @Section, @Address, @CN, @BD, @Age )", cn)
        With cm
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@studID", txtID.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@LN", txtLN.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FN", txtFN.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@MI", txtMI.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", cmbCourse.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", cmbYear.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", cmbSec.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", cmbAdd.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CN", txtCN.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@BD", dtpBD.Text)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", lblAge.Text)
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With

        cn.Close()
        MsgBox("Successfully added Student", vbCritical)
        With frmList
            .Loadrecords()
        End With
        Clear()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    cn.Close()
    MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
End Try
```

Comment: How can i make it valid ?

Comment: First things first, a title and some code is not a proper question. You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem in the question and then a summary in the title. You need to specify exactly what you're trying to achieve, how you're trying to achieve it and what happens when you try. You've basically said "it's not working" and that is unacceptable. Spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is irrelevant. That's a management tool. It has nothing to do with your application connecting to your database.

Comment: what other database can i use that is still mySQL ?

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) for correct INSERT statement syntax.

Comment: That's a nonsensical question. MySQL **IS** the database. That's like eating a banana and then asking *"what other fruit can I eat that is still a banana"*. MySQL is a database. MySQL Workbench is a management tool for MySQL databases. You might use Workbench to create the database in the first place or you may use some other management tool, but none of that is relevant when your app is connecting to it because none of them are involved.

Answer (score 0):

Your Insert Statement is wrong:

```
cm = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO stud (@studID, @LN, @FN, @MI, @Course, @Year, @Section, @Address, @CN, @BD, @Age )", cn)
```

you didn't define the columns you will insert into.
Do it like this:

```
cm = New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO [stud] ([Column1], [Column2], [Column3], [Column4]) values (@value1 , @value2 , @value3 , @value4)", cn)
```

with replacing (Column) with the correct column name